# Write error in r using trycatch

Tags: r, try-catch

I have used trycatch so that if error happened during execution of r code it will not break.

I wanted to write error in one of the file , but not sure how it can be done.

Below is code used

```
library(forecast)
library(data.table) 
library(RODBC)


forecast_data <- data.frame(Project_ID=character(),
                            Period_End=character(),
                            Point_Forecast=character(),
                            Lower_Limit_95=character(),
                            Upper_Limit_95=character(),
                            stringsAsFactors=FALSE)  

Data <- read.csv("Data.csv", header=TRUE,na.strings=c("NULL",""))[ ,c('Project_ID', 'Period_End_Date', 'Overall_Backlog_Processing_Efficiency_Incident')]

result = tryCatch({


  if (nrow(Data) >= 1)
  { 
    backlog <- as.vector(Data$Overall_Backlog_Processing_Efficiency_Incident)

    i <- 1
    datalist = list()

    for (i in 1:8) {

      backlogts <- tbats(backlog)
      fc2 <- forecast(backlogts, h=1)
      fc2

      fc_2 <- as.data.frame(fc2)

      fc_2$i <- i  # maybe you want to keep track of which iteration produced it?
      datalist[[i]] <- fc_2 # add it to your list

      backlog <- append(backlog,round(fc_2[1,1], digits = 2))

      i <- i +1

    }

    forecast_data = do.call(rbind, datalist)
    forecast_data$`Point Forecast` <- round(forecast_data$`Point Forecast` , digits = 3)

    nextweekday <- function(date, wday) {
      date <- as.Date(date)
      diff <- wday - wday(date)
      if( diff < 0 )
        diff <- diff + 7
      return(date + diff)
    }

    a <- tail(Data$Period_End_Date, n=1)
    a <- as.Date(a, "%d-%b-%y")
    b <- tail(Data$Project_ID, n=1)

    Period_End_Date <- data.table(date=seq(as.Date(nextweekday(a,1)), by=7, length=8), key="date")
    forecast_data  = cbind(forecast_data, Period_End_Date)
    names(forecast_data)[names(forecast_data) == 'date'] <- 'Period_End'
    forecast_data$Period_End <- as.character(forecast_data$Period_End)
    forecast_data$Project_ID <- b
    forecast_data <- forecast_data[c(8,7,1,4,5)]
    names(forecast_data)[names(forecast_data) == 'Lo 95'] <- 'Lower_Limit_95'
    names(forecast_data)[names(forecast_data) == 'Hi 95'] <- 'Upper_Limit_95'
    names(forecast_data)[names(forecast_data) == 'Point Forecast'] <- 'Point_Forecast'
  }

},
warning = function(w) {},
error = function(e) {
  forecast_data <- data.frame(Project_ID=character(),
                              Period_End=character(),
                              Point_Forecast=character(),
                              Lower_Limit_95=character(),
                              Upper_Limit_95=character(),
                              stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  print(paste("MY_ERROR:  ",e))
})
```

I tried to print error   print(paste("MY_ERROR:  ",err)) under error = function(e), but it is not working

Is there anything I am missing. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help

```
foo <- function(x){
  output <- tryCatch(x, error = function(e) e)
  ifelse(is(output, "error"), "error", "no error")
}

foo() # error
foo(1) # no error
```

Alternatively, use `purrr`.

```
foo <- function(x){
  x
}
foo_safe() # error
foo_safe(10)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was able print error message, I removed code "warning = function(w) {}," from script and was able to print error message. Not sure what problem was causing above line.